# Can springframework.net be used in a windows mobile applciation?

Tags: windows-mobile, spring.net

Can springframework.net be used in developing windows mobile applications?  (Mainly the AOP and IoC bits)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this isn't possible. For IoC you have the following options:

- [ninject](http://ninject.org/)
- [compactcontainer](http://code.google.com/p/compactcontainer/)